# How to crop two images and splice into one in iOS Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, png, sprite-kit, crop

I am developing a game for the AppStore in Xcode's Sprite kit. I have some single colored shapes that I want to 'splice' together into one, and have the user be able to drag and drop this spliced image as they would with the single colored shapes.

In more detail: I have the following two images:
http://s1381.photobucket.com/user/shahmeen/media/CircleYellow_zps11feede7.png.html
http://s1381.photobucket.com/user/shahmeen/media/CircleRed_zps49eb1802.png.html

```
SKSpriteNode *spriteA;
spriteA = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"CircleYellow"];
[self addChild:spriteA];
SKSpriteNode *spriteB;
spriteB = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"CircleRed"];
[self addChild:spriteB];
```

I would like to have a third sprite, that looks as it does below (forgive me for my crude photoshop skills ... if the links aren't working, what I want to create is an image, spriteC, with the left half of it being the left half of spriteA and the right half of it being the right half of spriteB):
http://s1381.photobucket.com/user/shahmeen/media/CircleRed_zps9ca710cb.png.html

```
(some code that crops spriteA and spriteB and then)
SKSpriteNode *spriteC;
spriteC = (the output of spriteA and spriteB cropped and spliced together);
[self addChild:spriteC];
```

I know I can do something like this using SKShapeNodes with the simplicity of the objects above, but I intend to do this with much more complex figures. Also I don't think it is practical for me to load in several .pngs because I'll be getting into the several hundreds count with all the permutations. I'll be happy to clarify anything - thanks

Comment: Read up on the SKCropNode Class Reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Or create the combined image to use as texture in code...

Comment: What/how do you mean by 'create the combined image'? I have 10 colors I want to use in game which comes out to 90 combinations (redYellow distinct from yellowRed), so I don't want to create all these images in photoshop and then add these to Xcode, I would like to do it programatically

Comment: the important part was "in code" ;) see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the final combination of the two images by code and make a `SKSpriteNode` use this combined image as texture. You can do it like follows, assuming the two images & the final one have the same size:

```
- (UIImage*)combineImage:(UIImage*)leftImage withImage:(UIImage*)rightImage{
    CGSize finalImageSize = leftImage.size;
    CGFloat scale = leftImage.scale;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(finalImageSize, NO, scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [leftImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(finalImageSize.width/2, 0, finalImageSize.width/2, finalImageSize.height)); //use clipToMask with a maskImage if you have some more complicated images
    [rightImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```